# Horizontal Tabbing Justification within Res Document Class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, document-classes, cv, resume, justification

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{res} 
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in} % increase text height to fit on 1-page
\newlength{\imagewidth}\setlength{\imagewidth}{4em}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{zsaveposx}{\let\zsaveposx\zsavepos}{}
\makeatother
\newcounter{hposcnt}
\renewcommand*{\thehposcnt}{hpos\number\value{hposcnt}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\schoolimage}[2][]{%
  \stepcounter{hposcnt}%
  \zsaveposx{\thehposcnt u}%
  \zref@refused{\thehposcnt u}%
  \llap{% Left margin (overlap)
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{% Remove vertical height + reposition
      \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,#1]{#2}% Insert logo
    }%
    \hspace*{-\dimexpr\zposx{\thehposcnt u}sp-\zposx{hpos0s}sp-\sectionwidth}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{\noindent\leavevmode\zsaveposx{hpos0s}}%

\begin{document} 
\begin{resume}
\section{PROFESSIONAL EXPERIENCE}
   \vspace{-0.04in}  
   \begin{tabbing}
   \hspace{2.3in}\= \hspace{2.7in}\= \kill % set up of the two tab positions
   \schoolimage{example-image-a}{\bfseries Job Title} \>Employer   \> 2018--2020\\
                             \>Baltimore, MD
   \end{tabbing}\vspace{-20pt} 
   \lipsum[12]
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

with the output

[image]

The positioning of the date range 2018-2020 is determined by `\hspace{2.7in}`. And so, it would be relatively easy to determine the amount of horizontal space needed in order to right justify this particular range of dates.

However, the format can easily differ amongst entries; e.g., 2021-Present, 2021, etc.

So, there is not one `\hskip` in this case which fits all.

We can manually force 2018-2020 to the right by using `~` a certain number of times, the number of which I have found out can change from entry to entry.

I tried using both `\hfill` and `hfil`; for example,

`\schoolimage{example-image-a}{\bfseries Job Title} \>Employer  \hfill  \> 2018--2020\\`

but this does not work.

QUESTION: Is there an automatic way of right justifying the date range, such as `\hfill` is able to do in other environments, so one does not have to keep making tedious manual adjustments such as `~~~~~`?

Thank you.

Comment: why `res` ? it is ancient basically `% RESUME DOCUMENT STYLE -- Released 23 Nov 1989`  with minor updates since, it is not included in texlive at all. Presumably you can use the standard tabbing `\\` ` ccommand to flush right that tab cell.

Comment: @David Carlisle Why `res`? Unfortunately, I encounter compilation problems when I try to use `resume`.

Comment: there are loads of maintained alternatives https://ctan.org/topic/cv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be just a question about tabbing, unrelated to `res` class (which is not in texlive due to its restrictive licence)

the `` \` ``  command flushes cell content to the right, compare these two tabbing examples

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

  \begin{tabbing}
   \hspace{1.3in}\= \hspace{1.7in}\= \kill % set up of the two tab positions
   {\bfseries Job Title} \>Employer   \> 2018--2020\\
                             \>Baltimore, MD
   \end{tabbing}

\noindent X\dotfill X

  \begin{tabbing}
   \hspace{1.3in}\= \hspace{1.7in}\= \kill % set up of the two tab positions
   {\bfseries Job Title} \>Employer   \` 2018--2020\\
                             \>Baltimore, MD
   \end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for answering another one of my questions, and for the link you just posted. I have learned a lot over the past several months from your answers. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to arrange and align the data using a tabular environment.
In this case, `tabular*` with a width of `\textwidth.`

The image is typeset outside of the `tabular*`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{res} 

\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in} % increase text height to fit on 1-page
\newlength{\imagewidth}\setlength{\imagewidth}{4em}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{zsaveposx}{\let\zsaveposx\zsavepos}{}
\makeatother
\newcounter{hposcnt}
\renewcommand*{\thehposcnt}{hpos\number\value{hposcnt}}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\schoolimage}[2][]{%
    \stepcounter{hposcnt}%
    \zsaveposx{\thehposcnt u}%
    \zref@refused{\thehposcnt u}%
    \llap{% Left margin (overlap)
        \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height-\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{% Remove vertical height + CHANGED <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,#1]{#2}% Insert logo
        }%
        \hspace*{-\dimexpr\zposx{\thehposcnt u}sp-\zposx{hpos0s}sp-\sectionwidth}%
    }%
}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{\noindent\leavevmode\zsaveposx{hpos0s}}%

\begin{document} 
\begin{resume}
    \section{PROFESSIONAL EXPERIENCE}
    
    \schoolimage{example-image-a}   
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}c r@{}}
        {\bfseries Job Title}   &Employer       & \\
            Assistant           & Baltimore, MD &2018--2020 \\
    \end{tabular*}
    
    \schoolimage{example-image-b}   
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}cr @{}}
        {\bfseries Job Title}   &Employer           & \\
                Manager         & New Horizon, MD   & 2020--Present\\
    \end{tabular*}
    
    \lipsum[12]
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this alternative approach.